# How to time Django queries

Tags: django, timeit

I've always used Python's `timeit` library to time my little Python programs.
Now I'm developing a Django app and I was wondering how to time my Django functions, especially queries.

For example, I have a `def index(request)` in my views.py which does a bunch of stuff when I load the index page.
How can I use `timeit` to time this particular function without altering too much my existing functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  [debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) is what you want, it helps you time each of your queries.

Alternatively this snippet works too.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/

Comment: Nice, I installed and configured debug_toolbar, it's a nice feature to have from the start.

Answer (score 30):

if your django project is in debug, you can see your database queries (and times) using:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
```

I know this won't satisfy your need to profile functions, but hope it helps for the queries part!

Answer (score 6):

The best way you can get is by using [Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar), you will also get some additional functionalities for Query optimization, which will help you to optimize your db query.

Here is another solution, You can use `connection.queries`. This will return the SQL command has been made for the command which was executed just before the `connect.queries` command. You can the reset_queries after getting the time of the previous query by using `reset_queries()`. Using `reset_queries()` is not mandatory.

Suppose you have a Model named **Device**. You can measure the query time like this:

```
>>> from django.db import connection, reset_queries
>>> from appname.models import Device
>>> devices = Device.objects.all()
>>> connection.queries
>>> reset_queries()
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone stumbling on to this checkout Sentry's approach.

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py#L476

You can replace `execute` and `executemany` with your owns functions that track the time it takes for execute to return.

A simple approach is to create custom context manager that initiates a timer and on exit writes final value of the timer to an array you pass to it.

Then you can just check the array.